# Converting WebP files to GIF doesn’t work as expected. Resulting GIF is glitchy

Tags: imagemagick, webp

I run command to convert WEBP into GIF but it's a bit "glitchy". Do I miss something?

- **Debian**: 11.8
- **ImageMagick**: 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25

```
convert -delay 10 sample.webp -loop 0 -layers optimize animation.gif
```

- [Original `webp` file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/lem85r81wkipxmhdubnsz/Bridget-idle-transparent.webp?rlkey=ur19unzo7xi9h5tx2frgz263q&dl=0).
- Converted `gif` file.

  > [image: Converted gif file.]

Another demo sample works fine like [Rainbow Nyan cat](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/animated-webp).

Comment: Hello, what's the point of the delay param? Anyways, let me guess, you're not using an up-to-date version of IM? If you are, what system are you on and how did you install IM? As it works perfectly fine on the latest one for me - no lost frames.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention those versions. Added it to main post

Comment: Yeah, that's not up-to-date IM. Start by upgrading then let us know if that still has the problem. From what I see you'll have to build 7.1 from source. Make sure to enable anything related to WEBP/GIF support.

Comment: Update IM and it works fine. I added delay param because the duration between frames playing weirdly while I'm using old version of ImageMagick to convert the webp. The latest one (v7.1.1-26) can just ignore this param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The installed ImageMagick (6.9.11-60) on your system is too out of date.

#### Update to a more recent version of ImageMagick like version 7.1.1-25.

This appears to work fine in my version ImageMagick (7.1.1-25) that is installed via Homebrew on macOS 14.2.1 on a MacBook Air (M2; 2022). Below is the output of the exact same ImageMagick command as you shared:

```
convert -delay 10 sample.webp -loop 0 -layers optimize animation.gif
```

My guess is your ImageMagick (6.9.11-60) is just too out of date to properly handle WEBP animations since WEBP is a very new image format and is in very [active development](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp).

> [image]

Here is how the same exact command works with the [Rainbow Nyan cat](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/animated-webp) image you shared. Looks fine to me! (*Note*: That Nyan cat is a GIF that was converted from a WEBP; please ignore the message in its graphic text.)

> [image]

Comment: I'm dumb. I didn't realize it and checked the software version first. v7.1.1-26 works fine.